# How to SELECT from the database to organize data like this report

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table where each record is: ID, groupID, and a notes field.
The ID is not unique, it can be associated with multiple groupIDs. And each ID-groupID combo can be associated with multiple notes. **The main data that I'm trying to print here is the notes field.**

```
id             | groupID    | notes
------------------------------------------------------------------
JWOFJ903JCKDF8 | groupID-22 | new id, new id-groupID combo
JWOFJ903JCKDF8 | groupID-33 | repeat id (line 1), new id-groupID combo
JWOFJ903JCKDF8 | groupID-33 | repeat id (lines 1&2), repeat id-groupID (line 2)
...
DF8#CKJ90JJ3WO | groupID-22 | new id, new id-groupID combo
DF8#CKJ90JJ3WO | groupID-44 | repeat id (line 4), new id-groupID combo
...
```

When printing the data, how can I SELECT the notes so that all notes that fall under the same ID-groupID combo are grouped together? and all groupIDs that fall under the same id are grouped together?

So my report would look something like this:

```
JWOFJ903JCKDF8
   -groupID-22
      - [line 1 of the data] new id, new id-groupID combo
   -groupID-33
      - [line 2 of the data] repeat id (line 1), new id-groupID combo
      - [line 3 of the data] repeat id (lines 1&2), repeat id-groupID (line 2)
DF8#CKJ90JJ3WO
   -groupID-22
      - [line 4 of the data] new id, new id-groupID combo
   -groupID-44
      - [line 5 of the data] repeat id (line 4), new id-groupID combo
```

I should point out that this table is very large - over 200,000 records and growing.

Comment: GROUP BY id then order by groupID, then you will have a pre-orded resource then you can consume on backend

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply in fact :

1/ select the desired records (ordered by id and groupId)

```
SELECT id,groupID,notes
  FROM <your table name>
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY id, groupID
 LIMIT ...
```

2/ limit results with a WHERE to retrieve results for a simple id and/or LIMIT (I doubt you want to show those 200k records in a single report). Read Mysql documentation for SELECT command

3/ on your front-end, use a variable to count result and indentate each time you change of id or groupID

If I may suggest, your database model should be changed like this :

- column id should be unique, like an autoincremental key
- a new column (let's call it key) should store the current id
- if the column groupId refer to an existing table group, change this table the same way:

  - an unique autoincremental id column, a name,
  - and in your record table, store only the group table id as the column name suggest